# Insert informational content in Video

Tags: windows, video, editing, comments

I've recorded a video clip and I'd like to add textual information at certain frames, similar to YouTube where you can add comments at certain screens.

Are there any apps available to achieve this? I have a Mac as well as PC (with Vista).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got Windows Vista, you might as well use [Windows Movie Maker](http://download.live.com/moviemaker), which is a free download if you don't already have it.

There are some instructions here (I have not tried it however):

[How to Add Titles and Text Overlays in Microsoft Movie Maker](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_2043597_add-titles-text-overlays-microsoft.html)